# Does any daemon run when spark is in local mode?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, daemon, bigdata

When we run Spark in local mode [by setting -Dspark.master=local[n] ] , it means N no of threads will be running to complete the job.

But does it start any daemons (Driver or Executors) in local jvm  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In local mode it starts single JVM process which includes single Driver (there is always one driver per spark app) and **only one executor collocated within the driver's JVM process**